# API key with Google Maps JavaScript API Library

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I am using the Google Maps JavaScript API (with my API KEY and billing turned on using a Credit Card) to retrieve a list of places & their details (using the AutoCompleteService).

However, when I go into the API Console, the usage tab shows absolutely no activity! I have had a look at the API console for both the "Google Maps JavaScript API v3" and also the "Places API".

I have added the SCRIPT file to my page as follows:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&libraries=places&sensor=false

So the question is, why can't I see the usage? 
Or would the usage ONLY be displayed if I exceed the 25,000 limit.

Comment: You should see usage in your API console for that key whether or not you have billing turned on.

Comment: Yes I agree, but I don't, thats the problem. I am not sure what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: Are your places and everything showing up as expected on your map? It's usually good practice to put the `libraries` param in the URL **before** the `key` param - this caused me issues in the past and despite searching I haven't been able to figure out why it's the case, it just is. This may help?